# Minecraft 1.14: How to check if a player has a position with a specific y-axis within a circular x,z area

Tags: minecraft-commands

Pretty much it's a climbing game. The first person to reach a certain height within the game boundaries wins. It's multiplayer so there could be people outside of the game at the specific y-axis as well. I need a command that will detect a player within the radius:

```
/execute if entity @a[x=244,z=345,distance=..2] run...
```

AND check if that specific player is ALSO at an exact y-axis:

```
/execute if entity @a[y=70] run...
```

If you picture it visually, I want the detection area to be a top-down circle instead of a sphere. Once a player reaches that detection area, it will run a command.
Hope you guys can help! Thanks :)

Comment: Is it okay if you run the command as a player? You should be able to combine your execute functions like so: `execute as @a[x=244,y=345,distance=..2] at @s if entity @s[y=70] run ...`. If that doesn't work I'd put every player's y coord in a scoreboard every tick and do everything the same as above but instead of `if entity @s` use `if score @s...`.

Comment: Ah, this problem again. I looked for a solution for very long and didn't find anything perfect, but a few very good approximations that are not too complicated or laggy. Linking as duplicate now.

Comment: Actually, there is indeed a perfect solution that I hadn't considered before! I'll change my answer over there.